# What's the best way to write a Perl CGI application?

Tags: perl, cgi

Every example I've seen of CGI/Perl basically a bunch of print statements containing HTML, and this doesn't seem like the best way to write a CGI app.  Is there a better way to do this?  Thanks.

EDIT: I've decided to use CGI::Application and HTML::Template, and use the following tutorial: http://docs.google.com/View?docid=dd363fg9_77gb4hdh7b.  Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Absolutely (you're probably looking at tutorials from the 90s). You'll want to pick a framework. In Perl-land these are the most popular choices:

- [CGI::Application](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?CGI::Application) - very lightweight with lots of community plugins
- [Catalyst](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Catalyst) - heavier with more bells and whistles
- [Jifty](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Jifty) - more magical than the above

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try them out and accept your answer when I get time to try them out (should be next week, I'm going on vacation :-))

Comment: I wonder if Jifty is still a good choice? Is it maintained? I note that it is being removed from Debian for not being widely used. The last update of Jifty to the CPAN was in 2011.

Comment: Yeah, Jifty should probably be removed from that list. But others have definitely risen up to take it's place. I'd now add Dancer and Mojolicious to that list.

Answer (score 11):

This is a really, really big question. In short, the better way is called [Model/View/Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller) (aka MVC). With MVC, your application is split into three pieces.

The Model is your data and business logic. It's the stuff that makes up the core of your application.

The View is the code for presenting things to the user. In a web application, this will typically be some sort of templating system, but it could also be a PDF or Excel spreadsheet. Basically, it's the output.

Finally, you have the Controller. This is responsible for putting the Model and View together. It takes a user's request, gets the relevant model objects, and calls the appropriate view.

mpeters already mentioned several MVC frameworks for Perl. You'll also want to pick a templating engine. The two most popular are [Template Toolkit](http://www.tt2.org/) and [Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/).

Answer (score 10):

Leaving the question of CGI vs MVC framework for the moment, what you're going to want is one of the output templating modules from the CPAN.

The Template Toolkit is very popular (Template.pm on CPAN)
Also popular are Text::Template, HTML::Template, and HTML::Mason.

HTML::Mason is much more than a template module, and as such might be a little too heavy for a simple CGI app, but is worth investigating a little while you're deciding which would be best for you.

Text::Template is reasonably simple, and uses Perl inside the templates, so you can loop over data and perform display logic in Perl.  This is seen as both a pro and con by people.

HTML::Template is also small and simple. It implements its own small set of tags for if/then/else processing, variable setting, and looping. That's it.  This is seen as both a pro and a con for the exact opposite reasons as Text::Template.

Template toolkit (TT) implements a very large, perlish template language that includes looping and logic, and much more.

I used HTML::Template one, and found I wanted a few more features.  I then used Text::Template with success, but found its desire to twiddle with namespaces to be a little annoying. I've come to know and love Template Toolkit. For me it just feels right.
Your mileage may vary.

Of course, there is still the old "print HTML" method, sometimes a couple of print statements suffices. But you've hit upon the idea of separating your display from your main logic. Which is a good thing.

It's the first step down the road to Model/View/Controller (MVC) in which you keep separate your data model&business logic (your code that accepts the input, does something with it, and decides what needs to be output), your your input/output (Templates or print statements - HTML, PDF, etc.) , and the code that connects the two (CGI, CGI::Application, Catalyst MVC Framework, etc.).  The idea being that a change to your data structure (in the Model) should not require changes to your output routines (View).

Comment: CGI vs MVC is nonsensical.  CGI (Common Gateway Interface) is a platform-independent interface for running external programs, software or gateways on a web/information server. MVC (Model–View–Controller) is a design pattern that divides an application into three areas of responsibility.  If you are using Perl to create a web app, you are going to be using CGI one way or another.  Using the MVC design pattern is optional and recommended, but ultimately unrelated to the use of CGI.

Comment: It is only nonsensical if you are pedantic about terminology, and insist on the denotative meanings of CGI and MVC, while ignoring their connotative meanings. While it is perfectly reasonable to build a CGI application using the MVC pattern, it is the case that programmers evolve from CGI.pm, CGI::Application, etc - creating their own MVC structure as the progress and refactor their code - to MVC frameworks like Catalyst, at which point they also tend to evolve into FCGI or mod_perl. So pragmatism,not nonsense.

Comment: Words mean things.  So do acronyms.  When we stop agreeing on that, we are back to grunting at each other in trees.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface

Comment: Thank you for agreeing with me.

Answer (score 5):

The [Perl5 Wiki](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?perl_5_wiki) provides a good (though not yet complete) list of [web frameworks](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?web_frameworks) & [templates](http://www.perlfoundation.org/perl5/index.cgi?templates).

The comparison articles linked in the "templates" wiki entry is worth reading.  I would also recommend reading this [push style templating systems](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=674225) article on PerlMonks.

For templating then [Template Toolkit](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Toolkit/) is the one I've used most and can highly recommend it.  There is also an [O'Reilly book](http://www.template-toolkit.org/book.html) and is probably the most used template system in the Perl kingdom (inside or outside of web frameworks).

Another approach which I've been drawn more and more to is non template "builder" solutions.  Modules like [Template::Declare](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Template-Declare/) & [HTML::AsSubs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tree/lib/HTML/AsSubs.pm) fit this bill.

Answer (score 4):

One solution that I feel strikes the right balance in the Framework/Roll-your-own dilemma is the use of three key perl modules: [CGI.pm](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/CGI.pm/CGI.pm.html#ABSTRACT), [Template Toolkit](http://www.tt2.org/) , and [DBI](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/DBI/DBI/FAQ.html#Basic_Information_amp_Information_So). With these three modules you can do elegant MVC programming that is easy to write and to maintain.

All three modules are very flexible with Template Toolkit (TT) allowing you to output data in html, XML, or even pdf if you need to. You can also include perl logic in TT, even add your database interface there. This makes your CGI scripts very small and easy to maintain, especially when you use the "standard" pragma.

It also allows you to put JavaScript and AJAXy stuff in the template itself which mimics the separation between client and server.

These three modules are among the most popular on CPAN, have excellent documentation and a  broad user base. Plus developing with these means you can rather quickly move to mod_perl once you have prototyped your code giving you a quick transition to Apache's embedded perl environment.

All in all a compact yet flexible toolset.

Comment: This is by far the best answer to the question asked.

Comment: I'd update my answer to urge consideration of Xslate, a fast templating solution. It has a TT syntax option for ease of migration from TT, and it is in the early stages of being ported to Golang.

Answer (score 2):

You can also separate presentation out from code and just use a templating system without needing to bring in all the overhead of a full-blown framework.  [Template Toolkit](http://www.tt2.org/) can be used by itself in this fashion, as can [Mason](http://www.masonhq.com/), although I tend to consider it to be more of a framework disguised as a templating system.

If you're really gung-ho about separating code from presentation, though, be aware that TT and Mason both allow (or even encourage, depending on which docs you read) executable code to be embedded in the templates.  Personally, I feel that embedding code in your HTML is no better than embedding HTML in your code, so I tend to opt for [HTML::Template](http://search.cpan.org/~samtregar/HTML-Template-2.9/Template.pm).