# What is a good Perl CGI tutorial?

Tags: perl, cgi

I am going to learn Perl CGI. Please suggest a good URL or book for a CGI tutorial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314654/whats-the-best-way-to-write-a-perl-cgi-application

Comment: @Donal Fellows: That question is different from this one, this is asking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try [Ovid's CGI Course](http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/).

Comment: Wayback machine has it: http://web.archive.org/web/20100825091937/http://jdporter.perlmonk.org/cgi_course/

Answer (score 2):

You might get some better answers if you explain a little more about what you know already and your plans for what to use CGI for.

I am assuming you know at least the basics of Perl already and are asking about CGI programming with Perl, not learning Perl itself.

If you are planning to use the CGI.pm module, I suggest reading the [manual for that module](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html). If you need a gentle introduction to the CGI.pm module, try [the fool's guide](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/cgi.html) which shows what CGI.pm is for.

There are many many alternatives to the CGI module, and indeed to CGI programming in general, however starting with the CGI and CGI.pm is still probably a good way for a beginner to learn. If you want to know about the alternatives, try asking some more specific questions (and searching).

Hope this helps.